# What is validity of an inference procedure?

Tags: inference, validity

What is validity of an inference procedure? The inference procedure can be point estimator, confidence interval, or a testing rule. I saw "validity" in Diggle et al's Longitudinal Data Analysis:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: The sentence following the use of "validity" explains *exactly* what is meant by not affecting validity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, "validity" means that you are doing what you think you are doing, while "reliability" and "efficiency" reflect how well you are doing something.

So... if you take a completely non-random sample of a population, then no matter what statistics you do, or how reliable or efficient they are, generalizing from them to the whole population won't be valid.

For example, suppose you are interested in the body sizes of adult humans. If your sample is professional basketball and football players, then the inferences will be invalid.

Comment: Thanks! In the book, for an estimator, does validity mean unbiasedness and or consistency?

Comment: I can't read Diggle's mind, but I would say it's closer to unbiasedness.

Comment: Are both validity and reliability not asympototic concepts?

Comment: I don't think so.... studies on very small samples can be valid.

Comment: ... or indeed invalid or unreliable. The validity or reliability of a procedure based on a small sample is very much to the point. Validity implies lack of bias, reliability implies low precision or variability. No asymptotics involved at all.